# Calculate link button text for total at gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I need your help. 
 Here I have aspx code and vb.net. 
I would like to calculate the content of my gridview which has templatefield (below). I'm using link button to deliver 'ID' with tooltip when I click the link button. The content of link button itself is amount of something, which is number and it supposed to be decimal or integer. 
I have problem when I want to make total at the footer. I want to calculate them (amount at link button) but the link button itself has string data type. 
 So, when I get `e.Row.Cells(0).text`, it shows "" (space/nothing).

I think, if `e.Row.Cells(0).text` could return the real text of 'amount', it would be more help.

Can you help me out with this? 
Thank you.

**ASPX code**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="right">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
        Text='<%#Eval("amount", "{0:###,##0}")%>' ToolTip='<%#Eval("id")%>'>
    </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
```

**VB.NET code**

```
Protected Sub gvList_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvList.RowDataBound
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    If Not IsNothing(e.Row.Cells(0).Text) And IsNumeric(e.Row.Cells(0).Text) Then
        arrTotalPage(j) += Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells(0).Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: where are you getting the `amount` from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest finding the control first in your code then using it's Text property to get the value e.g.

```
Protected Sub gvList_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvList.RowDataBound
     Dim j As Integer = 0

     If e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

          // Find the button
          Dim totalButton As LinkButton = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lnkEdit"), LinkButton)

          arrTotalPage(j) += Convert.ToDecimal(totalButton.Text)

     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The suggested code will throw a **format exception** at line number #6. where you are trying to convert **text** into decimal as the amount usually have number format e.g. **$100,000.00**

Comment: yeah, I see. Thanks @SuprabhatBiswal.

Comment: well.. thank you so much @d-unit. It helps a lot. I didn't think to use findcontrol the link button cause actually i have some fields in gridview, so I used `e.Row.Cells(i)` for array.